# Setting the CellStyle in the CellFormatting event raises an exception on mouse over

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with the following event. However, when the mouse pointer hovers over the cells whose `CellStyle` has been set, the application raises an exception.

```
DataGridViewCellStyle AStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor = Color.Green };

private void DGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()))
    {
        e.CellStyle = AStyle;
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
base.OnMouseMove(e);
```

> $exception  {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: font"}   System.ArgumentNullException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is basically telling you that the `Font` property of the `DataGridViewCellStyle` cannot be null when it's used to set the `CellStyle`. Change how you initialize your `AStyle` variable to something like this:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle AStyle;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor = Color.Green, Font = DGV.Font };
}
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of `AStyle` completely (if you're only using it to set the back color) and use something like this instead:

```
e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

One more thing to note is that `e.Value.ToString()` may throw a NullReferenceException if `e.Value` is null. You may consider adding a [null-conditioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to avoid this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value?.ToString()))
{
    e.CellStyle = AStyle;
}
```

Comment: I read that `cell.Style = AStyle` is preferred than `cell.Style.Attribute = ...` because the later one will create a new instance of `DataGridViewCellStyle` every time when assigning. So I followed the same pattern for `CellStyle`. When setting `Cell.Style` in the `RowsAdded` event, it doesn't need `Font` though.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I don't know if that's true or not (I don't see any good reason for it to be cloned every time since it's a _mutable_ class). However, if you look at the examples [in the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle), you see that they use `e.CellStyle.SomeProperty` as well. That being said, if you're not sure, you can still use the `AStyle` variable as shown in the first code block of the answer; just make sure that you set all the required properties (since you're initializing a _new_ instance as opposed to modifying an existing one).

Comment: I read it from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/best-practices-for-scaling-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control